# How can I serialize a MongoDB ObjectId with Marshmallow?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, marshmallow

I'm building and API on top of Flask using marshmallow and mongoengine. When I make a call and an ID is supposed to be serialized I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: ObjectId('54c117322053049ba3ef31f3') is not JSON serializable
```

I saw some ways with other libraries to override the way the ObjectId is treated. I haven't figured it out with Marshmallow yet, does anyone know how to do that?

My model is:

```
class Process(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, unique=True)
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class ProcessSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "created_at", "name")
```

And the view:

```
class ProcessView(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        process = Process.objects.get_or_404(id)
        return ProcessSerializer(process).data
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you just pass `Meta.fields` to a schema, Marshmallow tries to pick a field type for each attribute.  Since it doesn't know what an `ObjectId` is, it just passes it on to the serialized dict.  When you try to dump this to JSON, it doesn't know what an `ObjectId` is and raises an error.  To solve this, you need to tell Marshmallow what field to use for the id.  A [BSON `ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html#bson.objectid.ObjectId) can be converted to a string, so use a `String` field.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class ProcessSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.String()

    class Meta:
        additional =  ('created_at', 'name')
```

You can also tell Marshmallow what field to use for the `ObjectId` type so that you don't have to add the field each time.

```
from bson import ObjectId
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

Schema.TYPE_MAPPING[ObjectId] = fields.String
```

Answer (score 2):

[marshmallow-mongoengine](http://marshmallow-mongoengine.readthedocs.io) does this:

> `Marshmallow-Mongoengine` is about bringing together a `Mongoengine` Document with a `Marshmallow` `Schema`.

```
import marshmallow_mongoengine as ma


class ProcessSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Process
```

It has an [`ObjectId`](https://github.com/touilleMan/marshmallow-mongoengine/blob/master/marshmallow_mongoengine/fields.py#L11) field that serializes/deserializes `ObjectId`s.

Comment: How is it possible to serialize a list of objects using marshmallow-mongoengine

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the fields.Field class to [create your own field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html). [Here's how marshmallow-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/marshmallow-mongoengine/blob/master/marshmallow_mongoengine/fields.py#L11) (mentioned in another answer) implements this:

```
import bson
from marshmallow import ValidationError, fields, missing

class ObjectId(fields.Field):
    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data):
        try:
            return bson.ObjectId(value)
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError("invalid ObjectId `%s`" % value)

    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj):
        if value is None:
            return missing
        return str(value)
```

and then:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    id = ObjectId()
```

(I found this useful when not using MongoEngine, just using pymongo)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @dcollien above, I extended fields.Field and created my own custom field with helpers, similar to how Marshmallow handles field types internally:

```
from marshmallow import fields, missing
from marshmallow.exceptions import ValidationError
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson.errors import InvalidId
import json

def oid_isval(val: Any) -> bool:
    """
    oid_isval [summary]

    Parameters
    ----------
    val : {Any}
        Value to be assessed if its an ObjectId

    Returns
    ----------
    val : bool
        True if val is an ObjectId, otherwise false
    """    
    if ObjectId.is_valid(val):
        return val
```

```
def ensure_objid_type(val: Union[bytes, str, ObjectId]) -> ObjectId:
    """
    Ensures that the value being passed is return as an ObjectId and is a valid ObjectId

    Parameters
    ----------
    val : Union[bytes, str, ObjectId]
        The value to be ensured or converted into an ObjectId and is a valid ObjectId

    Returns
    ----------
    val : ObjectId
        Value of type ObjectId
        
    Raises
    ----------
    ValidationError: Exception
        If it's not an ObjectId or can't be converted into an ObjectId, raise an error.
            
    """
    try:
        # If it's already an ObjectId and it's a valid ObjectId, return it
        if isinstance(val, ObjectId) and oid_isval(val):
            logger.info(f"It's an ObjectId and it's valid! = {val}")
            return val
        
        # Otherwise, if it's a bytes object, decode it and turn it into a string
        elif isinstance(val, bytes):
            val = ObjectId(str(val.decode("utf-8")))
            logger.info(f"Decoded and converted bytes object to ObjectId! = {val}")

        # Otherwise, if it's a string, turn it into an ObjectId and check that it's valid 
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            val = ObjectId(val)
            logger.info(f"Converted str to ObjectId! = {val}")
        
        # Check to see if the converted value is a valid objectId
        if oid_isval(val):
            logger.info(f"It's a valid ObjectId! = {val}")
            return val
    except InvalidId as error:
        logger.error(f"Not a valid ObjectId = {val} | error = {error}")
        raise ValidationError(json.loads(json.dumps(f"{error}")))
```

```
class ObjectIdField(fields.Field):
    """Custom field for ObjectIds."""
    # Default error messages
    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid_ObjectId": "Not a valid ObjectId."
    }

    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs) -> Optional[ObjectId]:
        if value is None:
            return None
        return ensure_objid_type(value)

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        if value is None:
            return missing
        if not isinstance(value, (ObjectId, str, bytes)):
            raise self.make_error("_deserialize: Not a invalid ObjectId")
        try:
            return ensure_objid_type(value)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as error:
            raise self.make_error("invalid_utf8") from error
        except (ValueError, AttributeError, TypeError) as error:
            raise ValidationError("ObjectIds must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string") from error
```